# Bind and dedicate a USB keyboard to an X11 screen?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, kubuntu, kodi, boxee

I have a boxee remote that basically registers itself as a USB keyboard (via the dongle) and for some strange reason, KDE 4.x (whichever one is included in kubuntu 10.10) allows my regular ps/2 keyboard to work on :0.0 and :0.1 however I am trying to dedicate XBMC to full screen on :0.1 and would like the remote to operate it independently of what I'm doing with my keyboard/mouse in screen :0.0.  Further exacerbating the issue, whenever the boxee remote's buttons are pressed when XBMC in :0.1 has focus, all of X restarts.

Should I be looking into starting 2 completely separate X server instances?  I'm so close to getting my ideal setup setup!

Thanks in advance for your kind suggestions/answers.

Answer (score 0):

Input (and output) devices are assigned per X server, not per screen, so you will need to run multiple X servers. Simply configure the X servers as to which devices they should explicitly be using, and Xorg will figure the rest out.

Comment: Thank you, will try it out later.  One potential issue I see is that the USB remote isn't statically connected so I'm not sure how I can really specify it explicitly in the 2nd Xorg conf file if it's potentially not connected?

Comment: That I'm not really sure of myself. You may need to do some hal/udev poking in order to get it assigned to one X server and not the other.